# Correct way to add a (lagging) watermark to a source which already has timestamps

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

First up, I'm very new to stream processing, feel free to correct me where I misunderstand concepts :)

I'm using Apache Fink.
My source is a `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, which already adds timestamps which it takes from Kafka.
In my processing I want to be able to use a watermark (the why is out of scope for this question).

What I'm after is the watermark generation behaviour as provided by the abstract class `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`.

But this class only provides a:
`public abstract long extractTimestamp(T element);`

Which if you override it gives you the element, but not the timestamp originally provided by `FlinkKafkaConsumer`

The `TimestampAssigner` interface implemented by `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` does provide a `public final long extractTimestamp(T element, long previousElementTimestamp)`, which does give you the previously assigned, in which case you could just re-use that. But this method is made final in `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`, and thus can't be used.

So my way of getting around this now is to copy/paste the source code of `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`, and rewrite it to use `previousElementTimestamp` as the timestamp.

My question is: *Is this indeed the best way to go about this, or is there a (better) alternative?*

I'm just surprised having to copy paste classes, I'm used to (spoiled by) frameworks designed so that such 'basic' functionality can be done with what's incuded. (Or mayby what I want is actually very esoteric :)

Comment: Did you read this docs 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#with-periodic-watermarks

Comment: I did read that. I guess the answer might be that yes, writing your own is the best way to go, and BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor is just a convenience in very specific cases (But not mine).

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head there @cranphin. It's a convenience thing and it's super easy to implement your own `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` which does something different.